# New to llvm - trying to make the files but getting collect2: fatal error

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, virtual-machine, llvm, ninja

I'm new to the llvm project was following the websites guide to setting up the project. I ran

```bash
cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

which worked fine but then when I ran

```bash
ninja -C build check-llvm
```

It mostly worked but eventually i get

```bash
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
```

I read somewhere that it had to with not enough memory but I allocated 150 gb space and its has 20 gb of ram. Some more information, I am running this Ubuntu on VMware Workstation 17 player. Any help would be great.

I'm not even sure where to start fixing the problem.